# How to get entier header content. Differences between postman and axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, postman

I try to get X-Auth-Token using axios. Postman returns me this: [postman header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekqEN.png)

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

const API_URL="http://localhost:8080/api/1.0";

class DataService {
  login() {
    const data = {
      'login': 'xxxxx';
      'password': 'yyyyy';
    };
    const options = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      data: qs.stringify(data),
      url: `${API_URL}/login`,
    };
    return axios(options);
  }
}

export default new DataService();
```

Script above return this:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBQzy.png)

I wonder why axios don't return me the same content like Postman? Is it depends with CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of CORS requests, browsers can only access the following response headers by default:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

If you would like your client app to be able to access other headers, you need to set the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header on the server:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Token, Uid
```

In nodejs

```
...
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  exposedHeaders: 'Authorization',
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
...
```

In the case you are sending the response in the way of
 `res.header('Authorization', "Bearer ${token}").send();`